# Can I anywhere get packages of ancient Ubuntu versions?

Tags: package-management

https://packages.ubuntu.com/ provides a list of packages of all versions of Ubuntu from Trusty.

There is also http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ ; however, while I can download ancient Ubuntu versions from there, can I also download packages for those ancient versions?

I don't really need the packages themselves; all I need is a list of package names (preferably properly categorized).

Comment: Old versions : http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/ → {main/, multiverse/, restricted/, universe/}.

Comment: Hello gaazkam! Can you explain a little more about what you're trying to accomplish? And also can you clarify what your end goal is: Do you want a list of all possible packages for a specific release--or for more than one older release? Do you just want to see if a limited set of packages is available for a specific old release? Or do you want to search all old releases for a list of packages?

Comment: If you just want to make sure some packages you need are available in an older release, you can use the `rmadison` command (e.g. `rmadison <packagename>` for a single package or `rmadison <package1> <package2> <etc..>` for multiple packages). rmadison is part of `devscripts` if you don't already have it.